# Call custom Controller on billing informaion on change country

Tags: magento-1.7, checkout, controllers, billing

Hello i want to call my custom controller on billing information page on-change country drop-down list.Whenever i change country form drop-down list it will call my custom controller.How can i do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because I'm not sure what the use case is hopefully the following will help you.

Add this to your billing.phtml file in your theme:

```
<script>
document.getElementById('billing:country_id').addEventListener('change',fireCustomController(this), false);
function fireCustomController(elem){
    new Ajax.Request('/your/custom/controller/country_id/'+elem.value, {
        method:'get',
        onSuccess: function(transport) {
            var response = transport.responseText || "no response text";
            alert("Success! \n\n" + response);
        },
        onFailure: function() { alert('Something went wrong...'); }
    });
}
</script>
```

It creates an event listener on the `change` event of the billing country select box. On change, it calls the function `fireCustomController`, and I've graciously added in some boilerplate code to formulate an Ajax request to that controller.

Because Magento uses a URL pattern of **route/controller/action**, any parameters that would usually be passed via querystring (e.g. ?country_id=4) can instead now be passed as key/val pairs denoted by successive slashes. In this example I've mocked it up for you such that country_id is the key, and the value of the billing dropdown is concatenated onto that for means of passing in the request.